# Is it possible to work pointer event none in ios?

Tags: css

Can anyone have idea about how to work `pointer-events: none` in `ios` operating system.

Using this i need to disable input box in ios devices.

please guide me if you have any idea about this.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking about within a web view, `pointer-events:none` is [currently supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events) in all major browsers except Opera Mini, so should work fine on iOS.      (But if the goal is to "disable an input field" you should probably do that by setting its `disabled` attribute instead of by blocking `pointer-events`.)

If you're asking about native code, CSS rules aren't relevant.

Comment: Thanks for guide me.